# UINavigationController leaves 12px gap at bottom when rotated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I have a very simple app: one `UIPageViewController` wrapped in a `UINavigationController` showing 4 `UIView`s with a 4px red border.

Transition style is set to `scroll` with a 23pt border.

The problem is that when I rotate the simulator to landscape format, there is an initial 12pt gap at the bottom that's not supposed to be there. The view should take over the entire screen.

When I scroll to the next page, the view jumps to the bottom and is laid out correctly.

When I leave out the navigation view controller, everything is laid out correctly.

When inspecting the view hierarchy, I see a `_UIQueuingScrollView` with the bounds of

```
x: 504
y: →12←
width:504 height: 320
```

What am I missing here?

Screenshot (the red border should be at the bottom):

[image: Red border should be at the bottom]

[image]

To reproduce:

1. Download the PhotoScroller sample project https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html
2. Open the main storyboard, select the page view controller
3. Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller
4. Run and rotate the simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" property which you can turn on/off in the xib.

Just turn off this option of the Page View Controller in Interface Builder, and it will work as your expectation.